# Not found import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.*

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I am trying to learn `Kotlin Flow`. And when I try to add

`import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.*` it is not resolving.

Can you please look at my dependencies and help to solve the problem?

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
```

```
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.1.0'
```

```
ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.61'
```

Please help me to solve the issue.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

From [the document](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines). Try to add the below dependence in to the `build.gradle` file(**in the app level**):

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.3.2'
}
```

Comment: For some reason I am not able to resolve `MutableSharedFlow`. any idea?

Comment: @AouledIssa i able to see that with the coroutine import

Answer (score 1):

The answer from John Le did not work for me, however this worked. Inside your `build.gradle.kts` (under dependencies) add:

`implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx", "kotlinx-coroutines-core", "1.5.2")`

You can read more about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69794647/unresolved-reference-kotlinx-in-kotlin-project)

Comment: Your answer is no different from the other one, only the dependency is changed.

Comment: The formatting/syntax is different. For some reason it only worked with my post and not the above which is weird.