# Unresolved reference kotlinx in Kotlin project

Tags: java, kotlin, intellij-idea, kotlin-coroutines, kotlinx

This line:

```
import kotlinx.coroutines.*
```

Gives me `Unresolved reference: kotlinx` error.

My project creation process is very basic:
In Intellij Idea: `New project -> Kotlin -> JVM`

My project structure:

[image: project structure kotlin]

Maybe I need to configure something somewhere?

SOLUTION:

I was creating my Kotlin app the wrong way. Finally I followed this tutorial: https://huongdankotlin.com/create-a-new-gradle-project-with-kolin-using-intellij.html

Then on kotlin (in src folder) -> new package -> kotlin file.

And then add `implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx", "kotlinx-coroutines-core", "1.5.2")` inside `dependencies` in the `build.gradle.kts`

Now it worked for me.

Comment: Add this line `implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx", "kotlinx-coroutines-core", "1.5.2")` inside `dependencies` in the `build.gradle.kts` file and sync your project.

Comment: @GlennSandoval can you maybe take a look at my project structure? I dont have any of these files it seems

Comment: It should be right in the root of your project folder.

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned in the [Android documentation about coroutines](https://developer.android.com/kotlin/coroutines) you need to add the dependency to it in your gradle file to be able to use it like

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.5.0'
}
```

EDIT: I missed that the question is not about an Android project. I'll leave the answer here as it might help android developers.